# Автоинкрементное поле в СУБД MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Как в Visual Studio (или SQL Server Mangement Studio) создать автоинкрементное поле именно физической БД? Если программно, то есть класс *DataColumn* и свойства *AutoIncrementSeed* и *AutoIncrementStep*, а вот на физическом уровне почему-то я таких параметров не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то делается это с помощью ключевого слова identity(seed,increment).

Comment: Точно, в SQL Server Mangement Studio есть 3 поля indenty; indenty seed; identity increment. А в VS все же не нашел. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: А,все,нашел,извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

там все просто, заходите в студию, правой кнопкой по таблице - проект, дальше щелкаете по полю, которое хотите сделать автоинкрементном, внизу ищете колонку спецификация вычисляемого столбца, ставите в ней да, ставите ей шаг 1 и начальное значение тоже 1.